# Increment each digit in a number to form a new number

Tags: c#, programming-challenge

Today I've found */r/dailyprogrammer* and I've solved an easy challenge. I'm new to coding and I'm not sure if this is good way to solve this kind of problems. Could you, please, give me some hints? How to make my code more clear and readable? Thanks!

> **Challange description:**
>
> A number is input in computer then a new no should get printed by
>   adding one to each of its digit. If you encounter a 9, insert a 10
>   (don't carry over, just shift things around).
>
> For example, 998 becomes 10109.
>
> **Bonus**
>
> This challenge is trivial to do if you map it to a string to iterate
>   over the input, operate, and then cast it back. Instead, try doing it
>   without casting it as a string at any point, keep it numeric (int,
>   float if you need it) only.

```
private static int Challange(int number)
        {
            int digits = (int)Math.Log10(number); //this is number of digits -1 
            int result = 0;
            for (int i=0; i <= digits; i++)
            {
                int tens = (int)(Math.Pow(10, digits - i));
                int currentDigit = ((number / tens) % 10);

                if (currentDigit == 9) result *= 10;
                result += (currentDigit + 1) * tens;
            }
            return result;
        }
```

Comment: Is 0 a valid input? If so, what should the result be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a matter of taste but I find a recursive solution to be reasonably readable :

```
private static int IncrementDigits(int number){
    if (number == 0){
        return 0;
    }

    int lastDigit = number % 10;
    int firstDigits = number / 10;

    if (lastDigit == 9){
        return 10 + 100 * IncrementDigits(firstDigits);
    } else {
        return lastDigit + 1 + 10 * IncrementDigits(firstDigits);
    }
}
```

Note that it only works for `number > 0`.

Here's a working example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/xUKs6M

Comment: You could use `System.Math.DivRem` to do the division and modulo operations (on .Net Core this would be faster, the .Net Framework implementation does the naïve thing of doing the division twice)

Comment: @mistertribs: Thanks. I wanted to stay close enough to OP's answer. I don't really like the output argument in `Math.DivRem`, to be honest.

Answer (score 8):

It works, but it's a bit tricky to follow the logic and work out why. If you work from the other end then you can avoid the `Log` and `Pow` and shifting the partial result, and I find that easier to read.

---

`Challange` is not a descriptive name. What does the method do? `IncrementDigits` might be a better name, for example.

Answer (score 2):

Computing powers repeatedly and log are not cheap operations.
You could substitute them with cheaper alternatives:

- Instead of computing powers of `tens`, you could start with `1` and multiply in the loop steps.
- Instead of computing the number of digits and using a counting loop, you could divide by 10 until reaching 0.

Something like this:

```
if (number == 0) {
  return 1;
}

int work = number;

int tens = 1;
int result = 0;
while (work > 0) {
  int digit = work % 10;
  work /= 10;

  result += tens * (digit + 1);
  tens *= 10;
  if (digit == 9) {
    tens *= 10;
  }
}
return result;
```